# Python -- sanity check on design of program

Tags: python, design-patterns, publish-subscribe

I have a project that I have laid out like this:

```
User
Interface
Interface Handler
Main
Network Handler
Networks
Elements Handler
Elements
```

The Interface is the gui, main is obvious, networks are wrappers for elements and define their interactions, elements are the smallest components.  This is a home security/automation program, elements are things like ZWave sensors, android phones, lights, the tv, etc, networks wrap them in logical groups like ZWave or Lights or Stations (Android phones, used with IP Webcam, pushing sound to them via Soundwire, etc).

Here's the issue -- getting deep into the project, it becomes a mess.  I have been using the idea that tiers below cannot know about tiers above but above can know about 1 tier below (except interface which knows nothing about anything) and can only communicate with the tier above it and does so via pubsub with only abstract messages that might be of interest.  Going down, I just use object method calls, object attribute changes, etc.  Am I approaching this correctly?  Once I start implementing complex interactions such as when a sensor is tripped and the away alarm is active, a bunch of things occur: lights all go on, monitors are switched to motion detect record, an email is sent with snapped pictures, etc.  These interactions get confusing and I've devolved to tightly coupling things.  When I try to loosely couple, I end up essentially making new languages so that everything speaks the same language.

One core problem is that I have wildly different elements.  ZWave speaks through OpenZWave, android stations speak through Zoneminder and/or soundwire, lights speak through http, etc.  Am I approaching this correctly?  Is there a better general design pattern I should be modeling?  Thanks.

Comment: I think this posting would be a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/); as it is, it is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to choose a messaging protocol, such as [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/), that all the elements can speak through. That way, each element can subscribe to the MQTT conversation and act appropriately when messages are published that concern them.

For example, each device could communicate its status when it changes on a status/# topic (status/living_room/window_1 -- OK). Then other parts of your system can subscribe to the status topic and react accordingly when something changes, such as status/living_room/window_1 -- ALARM or something like that.

You could also have a topic for devices to issue commands to other devices that don't speak the same language. For example, a command/# topic where user input from a Web page to turn off a light might publish command/living_room/light1 -- OFF and the Zwave module that controls the light can listen in and act on the message.

Looking at the log of MQTT messages is a great way to see exactly what's going on in your system, because it's a conversation among devices as they report status and interact with one another.

MQTT is extremely well-supported on just about every platform. There are clients for Python, Arduino, PHP, JavaScript, Node.js, C/C++, Java, etc.